# Highlight current tab page?

Tags: tabs, highlight

Is there a way to highlight the current tab in my navigation bar?:

[image]

Im using 1 html file with multiple tabs. A little snippet of my navigation code:

```
    <div id="nav">
    <ul id="ulnone">
      <a href="#" class="navbutton" onclick="return show('fixed-tab-1');">Mijn Profiel</a>
      <a href="#" class="navbutton" onclick="return show('fixed-tab-2');">Ranglijsten</a>
      <a href="#" class="navbutton" onclick="return show('fixed-tab-3');">Voorspellingen!</a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using jQuery it can be as simple as:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/BKweBj

```
jQuery:
   $(".tab").click(function () {
   $(".tab").removeClass("active");
   $(this).addClass("active");  
});
```

Let me know if you cannot use jQuery for whatever reason

And with a default active:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ONORmG

Comment: Thank you, sounds good! Could you please show me the java code u used? Sorry, im really bad at java

Comment: Thank you! Will let you know when I get home from school

Comment: It worked! @excojish Thank you. Now, is there a way to make 'profiel' highlighted when page loads in?

Comment: Grats! You could just give that one the class of active in your html :)

Comment: Just like this? @excojish

<!-- Tabs-->
      <div id="nav">
        <ul id="ulnone">
          <a href="#" class="navbutton" class="active" onclick="return show('fixed-tab-1');">Mijn Profiel</a>
          <a href="#" class="navbutton"  onclick="return show('fixed-tab-2');">Ranglijsten</a>
          <a href="#" class="navbutton"  onclick="return show('fixed-tab-3');">Voorspellingen!</a>
        </ul>
      </div>

Comment: That doesn't seem to work, I added javascript to add a class, but then the class won't dissapear when clicking another tab:

window.onload = function() {
  document.getElementById('active').className = 'active';
};

Comment: Could you mark this as answered please? Also - Don't hesitate to PM me at any time :)

Comment: Hey @excojish, Is there a way to contact you? Seems like I can't pm you. Perhaps over skype?

Comment: ButButILYqq is my Skype :)